# Using RegEx to get numbers from string, but not getting results expected

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string:

`string OnClick = "TxtLinkAction(18294,18298)"`

I'm using the following line of code to get the numbers from the string:

`var numbers = Regex.Split(OnClick, @"\D+");`

I was expecting to get two results:

```
numbers[0] = "18294"
numbers[1] = "18298"
```

But, I'm getting the following results, instead:

```
numbers[0] = ""
numbers[1] = "18294"
numbers[2] = "18298"
numbers[3] = ""
```

So, I'm wondering, why am I getting four results?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If your separator is always a comma, use [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) as it should be faster and in my opinion it is more readable.

Comment: @Jasd He wants to extract the numbers in the text. `String.Split` would be very cumbersome to use in this case. Notice that it's not just two numbers separated by a comma. In my opinion, `Regex` is much better in this case.

Comment: Ahh I totally skipped what `OnClick` really contains, my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want Regex.Matches http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches%28v=vs.110%29.aspx instead of Regex.Split.

Edit:
You also want to change \D to \d. "\D" matches any non-digit.

Comment: I tried using Regex.Matches and the collection returned had three entries `numbers[0] = "TxtLinkAction("`, `numbers[1] = ","` and `numbers[2] = ")"`.

Comment: That worked!  I used `RegEx.Matches` and the lowercase `"d"`.  Thanks so much!